# shiny DT::renderdatatable

Tags: datatable, shiny, reactive

suppose the columns of a data table  are:  unique-ID, name, salary, position.
I display the table in a shiny application using DT::renderdatatable (DT::dataTableOutput).
I would like to click on a row of the output to display other data of the person belonging to the ID in another output.
what is the solution?
in short, how do I extract the unique-ID from a clicked line item?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `_rows_selected` extension coming with `DT` tables. [Here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html)'s the list of possible arguments. Several live examples are [here](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-rows/) or [here](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-info/).

This is a simple example of a plot that updates with the lines selected in the table:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("test_table"),
  plotOutput("test_plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$test_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    mtcars
  })

  output$test_plot <- renderPlot({
    s <- input$test_table_rows_selected

    if (!is.null(s)) {
      plot(mtcars[s, "disp"])
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```